# How can I get my animation loop working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to implement an animation loop to work around the slight delay I was getting when moving a canvas item after hitting an arrow key but am now stuck. My code is shown below and I thought that this would enable a loop to run when a key was pressed and for the loop to stop when the key was lifted, but running the program doesn't result in the canvas item moving at all. Firstly, is the idea for the animation loop correct and secondly where do I / should I not call the 'move' function to get the item moving? Please help - thanks!

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10
a = 100
b = 100
direction = None

def move():
    global x_vel
    global y_vel
    global direction
    if direction is not None:
        canvas1.move(rect, x_vel,y_vel)
        after(33,move)

def on_keypress(event):
    global direction
    global x_vel
    global y_vel
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        direction == "left"
        x_vel = -5
        y_vel = 0
    if event.keysym == "Right":
        direction == "right"
        x_vel = 5
        y_vel = 0
    if event.keysym == "Down":
        direction == "down"
        x_vel = 0
        y_vel = 5
    if event.keysym == "Up":
        direction == "up"
        x_vel = 0
        y_vel = -5

def on_keyrelease(event):
    global direction
    direction = None


window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")

#canvas and drawing
canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 200, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b]
rect = canvas1.create_rectangle(*coord, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")

#capturing keyboard inputs and assigning to function
window.bind_all('<KeyPress>', on_keypress)
window.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', on_keyrelease)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `move` is never called.
2. `after` should be called with `widget`.

   ```
   def move():
       global x_vel
       global y_vel
       global direction
       if direction is not None:
           canvas1.move(rect, x_vel,y_vel)
       window.after(33,move)  # Indetation.
   ```
3. Typo in assignment to the `direction`: `==` should be `=`.

   ```
   direction = "left"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Repetitive code like

```
if event.keysym == "Left":
    direction == "left"
    x_vel = -5
    y_vel = 0
if event.keysym == "Right":
    direction == "right"
    x_vel = 5
    y_vel = 0
if event.keysym == "Down":
    direction == "down"
    x_vel = 0
    y_vel = 5
if event.keysym == "Up":
    direction == "up"
    x_vel = 0
    y_vel = -5
```

can usually be written more compactly.  At module scope, define a dict.

```
dir_vel = {
    'Left': ('left', -5 0),
    'Right': ('right', 5, 0),
    'Down': ('down', 0, 5),
    'Up': ('up', 0, -5),
}
```

Then inside on_keypress, replace the alternations above with

```
    direction, x_vel, y_vel = dir_vel[event.keysym]
```